# Defining html code inside PHP variables

Tags: php, html, variables

I want to include html code inside php variables.
I remember there was a way to define html code inside a php variable, something similar to this:

```
<?php $my_var = { ?>
<div>SOME HTML</div>
<?php } ?>
```

I found it on `PHP.net` but I can't find it now.
There was something else instead of the `"{"` but I don't remember exactly.
I am looking to directly write the html code like above, so NOT like this: `$my_var = '<div>SOME HTML</div>';`
Any ideas?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
<?php
$my_var = <<<EOD
<div>SOME HTML</div>
EOD;
?>
```

It's called [heredoc](http://php.net/heredoc) syntax.

Comment: I was hoping that Dreamweaver will help with formatting the html syntax properly but I see it doesn't recognize it as a html :| I cannot close that php tag before html and open it again after the html, can I ?

Comment: No, unfortunately, you can't :-/
You can use ob_start() and ob_get_clean() to begin saving the output buffer, and then fetching the buffer into a variable. That's considered an (ugly) hack, though.

Comment: Got it. I didn't like the ob_start() eider whenever I seen it.

Comment: It is not considered ugly hack. Use that if it eases your work and makes you feel better. Nobody will notice that tiny speed difference.

Comment: Rok, I'm not talking about performance. I'm talking about software architecture. Using the output buffer to fetch data into variables is not a clean and maintainable approach.

Comment: ob_start() seems to be a very extreme solution in any case, and I can imagine all kind of bugs with page loads, scripts, etc.

Answer (score 111):

Try this:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<div>HTML goes here...</div>
<div>More HTML...</div>
<?php $my_var = ob_get_clean(); ?>
```

This way you will retain syntax highlighting for HTML.

Comment: This method seemed to work the best if you have additional php code inside the html.

Comment: Some references for or elaboration on the functions here would be useful.

Answer (score 11):

Save your HTML in a separate file: `example.html.` Then read in the contents of the file into a variable

```
$my_var = file_get_contents('example.html');
```

Comment: Yes, this method would also work for the initial purpose I had.

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to be echoing the content then another way this can be done is by using functions,

this also has the added benefit of programs using syntax highlighting.

```
function htmlContent(){
?>
    <h1>Html Content</h1>
<?php
}


htmlContent();
?>
```

Comment: IMO the most elegant approach, allowing to pass parameters and include php inside the element like this `<?php MyElement("some text"); ?>` , thanks for this tip =)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about HTML syntax highlighting you could just define a normal variable. You don't have to escape HTML either because PHP lets you use single quotes to define a variable, meaning you can use double quotes within your HTML code.

```
$html = '
 <p>
  <b><i>Some html within a php variable</i><b>
 </p>
 <img src="path/to/some/boat.png" alt="This is an image of a boat">
' ;
```

Works perfectly for me, but it's a matter of preference and implementation I guess.

Answer (score 1):

To define HTML code inside a PHP variable:

1) Use a function (Ref: @RedSparr0w)

```
<?php
function htmlContent(){
?>

    <h1>Html Content</h1>

<?php
}
?>
```

2. Store inside a variable

```
$var = htmlContent();
```

Comment: No idea why this is upvoted, that's not how you store an echoing into your variable. `$var = htmlContent();` will just echo the HTML and assign `NULL` to `$var`

Answer (score -1):

To add to the few answers that mention using a function in the var. may I suggest an [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). I'm not a php wizard so please correct me if I'm wrong, but I would imagine it working something like the following:

```
<?php
$my_var = function(){
   ?>
   <div>SOME HTML</div>
   <?php
};

// Display content
$my_var();
```

To extend this even further, if other php content is needed in the html it could be passed in a few different ways.

```
$method1 = "Title"; // Will be the same for every instance 
$method2 = "default content"; // Can change for each instance
$my_var = function($unique=$method2/*set default*/) use ($method1){
   ?>
   <h1><?php echo $prop1; ?></h1>
   <div><?php echo $unique; ?></div>
   <?php
};

// Display content

$my_var();
//returns
```

## Title

default content

```
$my_var("Some unique content");
//returns
```

## Title

Some unique content

Answer (score -1):

How can I use this array, in the tr, td section of html and assign this html content to a php variable $data.

```
$student = [
'saurabh' => 26,
'John' => 20,
'Ross' => 30 
];

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.lft {
    padding: 0px 80px 10px 5px;
}
td {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Saurabh</td>
    <td>26</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```