# php - set variable to html markup via include statement

Tags: php

Working with a phpmailer function, having to format the email inside a variable with double quotes is becoming a nightmare.

```
$body = "<div><h1>Hello, ".$foo."!</h1></div>";
```

It's like this for the entire body of the email, which is extensive, and gets hard to troubleshoot as my editor (KomodoEdit) doesn't recognize syntax errors and such which the markup is defined within a string.

I've been looking into other ways of accomplishing this such as the [heredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305869/defining-html-code-inside-php-variables) method, but while this looks cleaner, it still doesn't allow me the utility of my editing software's syntax check and tag collapsing.

My next step was to try something like this:

**body.php**

```
<div><h1>Hello, $foo !</h1></div>
```

**index.php**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$foo = 'Frank';

$page = include('body.php');

$body = <<<EOD
        $page
        EOD;
```

But this doesn't post anything and I don't even get any errors reported.  I've been through the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) but am either missing something in the syntax or it's a logical error where `<<<EOD` is to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EOD; can't have any whitespace before.  Move it left.  However that still won't do what you want.

```
ob_start();
include('body.php');
$page = ob_get_clean();
```

I would never adjust my application to meet the syntax highlighting or any other capabilities of an editor!

Comment: The heredoc is unneccesary (and won't work as intended here). `$page` will already contain the results of the template if it's modified to do `<?php echo $foo ?>`

Comment: I really just want to set the content of `body.php` to a string variable and then include it to the `$body` variable for use in other functions.  But `body.php` has to include previously defined variables within from executed root doc.  Also, setting `<php? echo $foo; ?>` seems tedious, but if that's the only way to do with without setting all the markup as a string, than so be it.  Also not trying to bend to the will of the text editor, the code would just seem easier to manipulate (and expand for other email templates) if it were in it's own file.

Comment: Just remove the heredoc and use $page.

Answer (score 0):

update your code

**index.php**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$_REQUEST['foo'] = 'Frank';

ob_start();
include('body.php');
$page = ob_get_clean();
```

**body.php**

```
"<div><h1>Hello, ".$_REQUEST['foo']." !</h1></div>"
```

we can only access a public variable (request etc) in included file

Comment: Still using string concatenation on HTML markup which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: But I do like the `$_REQUEST` part.

Comment: $body = <<<EOT
        $page
        EOT;

Comment: check example 2 from http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1) **index.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$foo = 'Frank';

$page = include('body.php');

echo <<<EOD
    $page
EOD;
?>
```

2) **body.php**

```
<?php
return <<<RESULT
    <div><h1>Hello, $foo !</h1></div>
RESULT;
?>
```

Comment: @tPlummer : please find above updated code of body.php without string concatenation. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

1) **index.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$foo = 'Frank';

$page = include('body.php');

echo <<<EOD
    $page
EOD;
?>
```

2) **body.php**

```
<?php
    return "<div><h1>Hello, ".$foo." !</h1></div>";
?>
```

Comment: Using string concatenation is exactly what the OP is trying to *avoid*.