# Php Function HTML Paramenter

Tags: php, html, function

I'm sure I'll get a lot of bad points for asking this.

But I know this works:

```
<?php
function line(){ ?>
2(Out of php)
<? } ?>
   1(Out of php)
<?php
echo line()
?>
```

But these do not work:

```
<?php
echo line( ?> text html <?php ); ?>
```

Or:

```
<?php
$html = ?> text html <?php ; ?>
```

Before anyone throws stones at me, I'll explain. I want to create a function that creates the div structure of the bootstrap, but these divs will have a lot of content and I do not want to write this all inside a php variable, or having to remember to call a function to close the tags  .

```
function divs($size, $html){ return 'Many divs('.$size.'%)'.$html.'Closing many div'; } 

//something like that
echo divs(40, ?> many many many html content <?php );

//I do not want to write as much string content
echo divs(40, 'many many many html content' );
```

Thanks for other ideas.

Comment: I found the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305869/defining-html-code-inside-php-variables

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to print PHP in html from printing html in PHP. For example,

```
<?php

function line(){

...code code code

?> 

<div> <?php echo $info ?> </div>

...hmtl html <?php echo $info ?> html
...hmtl html <?php echo $info ?> html

<?php 

...continuity of code
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
jsFunction();
</script>

<?php
}

?>
```

Comment: That's not exactly it. I want the same function to use on all pages, what changes is the HTML content within the function that is specific of page.

Comment: maybe you can use parameters in the above function.But the logic is ...i think

Comment: Yes, global variables, parameters in the function, I had already thought of each one of these. But I find it very bad to type large amounts of HTML into PHP variables. So I was looking for an alternative.