# How can I style PHP code using HTML tags?

Tags: php, html, html-email

I am triggering an email to be sent with data from a filled out form once a submit button has been clicked. The email successfully sends with the correct data, however, I am wanting to be able to apply some basic styling to the email such as some `<h3>` or `<strong>` tags. Am I able to do this within my php `$message` variable, and if so, what would that look like?

```
<?php 
    $to = "test@test.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = "test@test.com"; // this is the sender's Email address

    $company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
    $rep_name = $_POST['rep_name'];
    $prod_type = $_POST['prod_type'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $zip = $_POST['zip'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $subject = "New Form Submission";

    $message =  "New Form Submission" . "\n" . "\n" .
                "Company Name: " . $company_name . "\n" .
                "Representative Name: " . $rep_name . "\n" .
                "Product Type: " . $prod_type . "\n" .
                "Address: " . $address . "\n" .
                "City: " . $city . "\n" .
                "State: " . $state . "\n" .
                "Zip: " . $zip . "\n" .
                "Phone: " . $phone . "\n" .
                "Email: " . $email . "\n";

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

**Edit:**
I have tried using ob_start() and ob_get_clean() that I found at this link [Defining html code inside PHP variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305869/defining-html-code-inside-php-variables) but had no success

Comment: @ADyson I've tried just adding html tags within the quotes and it just prints out the tag itself. I also tried ob_start() and ob_get_clean() that I found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305869/defining-html-code-inside-php-variables but didnt have any success with it

Comment: That's because there's more to it than that. HTML comes in distinct flavours - plain text and email are the main ones. If you simply put HTML tags into a plain-text email, it won't be treated as HTML by the receiving mail client. Follow one of the guides in the link I gave you , e.g. this one perhaps https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/ . P.S. that link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305869/defining-html-code-inside-php-variables is not really relevant to your question. Certainly ob_start and ob_get_clean are not needed.

Comment: @ADyson Perfect, this looks like what I need, thanks for the direction!

Comment: I would recommend that you use one of the tried and tested mail libraries, like PHPMailer, SwiftMailer etc, instead of using the low level mail-function. It will make it _much_ easier to send multi-part emails (containing both HTML and text versions)

Comment: There's no HTML in this code. `\n` in HTML would not render a new line.

Answer (score 3):

Set `Content-Type: text/html` header to enable HTML emails;

```
$headers = "From:" . $from;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html";
```

Add some HTML elements to the email;

```
$message = <<<EOL
    <h1>Hi!</h1>
    <h2>HTML Emails are awesome!</h2>
EOL;
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

---

Small working example;

```php
<?php

$to = '----';
$subject = 'SO test Mail';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$message = <<<EOL
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hi!</h1>
        <h2>HTML Emails are awesome!</h2>
    </body>
</html>
EOL;

if ($res = (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))) {
    echo 'OK';
} else {
    echo 'Error';
    var_dump($res);
}
```

[image]